# Representability of a subfunctor of the functor of points of a group scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

Let $G$ be a group scheme over a scheme $S$ and $h_G:\rm{Sch}/S\longrightarrow \rm{Grp}$ the functor of points represented by $G$.

Let $k$ be a subfunctor of $h$. Is $k$ representable? If so, can we represent it by a (locally closed) subscheme of $G$ over $S$?

My question might be very naïve, but it is justified by a lack of familiarity with group schemes.

Comment: No. There are even fppf subsheaves which are not representable by a scheme. You can construct such a subsheaf by “removing” the generic point of a connected algebraic group over a field. Such an example already appears somewhere on MO. I will look it up as soon as I get the chance.

Comment: A simple example: take for $G$ the additive group $\mathbb{G}_{a,S}$. For an $S$-scheme $T$, $h_G(T)$ is just the additive group $\Gamma(T,\mathscr{O}_T)$. The subgroup of locally nilpotent elements is a group subfunctor (even an fppf subsheaf) which is not representable.

Comment: @Laurent Moret-Bailly: thank you for your counterexample. Feel free to put it as an answer: I would mark the question as solved.